# Using present tenses after past tenses

Tags: tense-agreement

Some teachers say that it's incorrect to use present or future tenses after past tenes, for example,
"She didn't tell me that it's not working."
Is that correct or I should say
"She didn't tell me that it didn't work."
Why in your opinion do some teachers say that it's incorrect?

Comment: It's a little awkward to use the *continuous* verb form in *She didn't tell me that it's not working* - better would be *She didn't tell me that it **doesn't work*** if you don't (optionally) "backshift" to ***wasn't working*** or ***didn't work.*** But your teachers don't know what they're talking about if they say "it's incorrect to use present or future tenses after past tenses". Obviously you can't use Present Tense if the fault has been fixed and it *does* work at time of utterance.

Comment: ...and as for Future Tense - *She **said** it **will be** a hard winter this year*. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Don't we have to use reported speech here?

Comment: I take it you mean ***indirect*** reported speech. Direct reported speech is, for example, *She said "My name is Jane"*, where indirect reported speech is *She said her name **was** Jane* (backshifted) OR *She said her name **is** Jane* (not backshifted, but note that ***my*** still has to be changed to ***her*** in indirect reported speech). That distinction doesn't really mean much with *She said it will be a hard winter this year*, where both versions *sound* identical (but the "direct" version would capitalize the first word she said, and enclose *"It will be a hard winter"* in quotes).

Comment: Backshifting is *optional* in indirect reported speech. We don't necessarily do it if something that was said in the past is *still* true when reporting that speech later.

Comment: You can't discuss if a wording is "correct" or "incorrect" without considering the intended meaning, as the answers here explain. Your question doesn't say what the phrase is intended to mean.

Answer (score 1):

English differentiates between situations where you're telling a story about the past, and where you're talking about the present but want to mention something that happened in the past that is still relevant in the present. There are also different ways of expressing things that are temporary and permanent/longer-term.

We have multiple possibilities (for an example I'll talk about a dishwasher machine in a restaurant, and you are a kitchen worker):

1. "She didn't tell me that the dishwasher is not working" - the dishwasher is temporarily out of order at the present moment, and you were not informed when you arrived for your shift. Now you'll have to do the dishes by hand, but it should be repaired soon.
2. "She didn't tell me that the dishwasher doesn't work" - the dishwasher is permanently out of order, and you weren't informed of this. You'll now have to spend a lot of time washing dishes and there's no plan to repair the dishwasher, although maybe they'll get a new one eventually.
3. "She didn't tell me that the dishwasher wasn't working" - You're talking about a situation in the past where you wanted to use the dishwasher but it was temporarily broken, and nobody had told you before then. The dishwasher may now be repaired or still broken.
4. "She didn't tell me that the dishwasher didn't work" - You're talking about a situation in the past where you wanted to use the dishwasher but it was broken on a more permanent basis. Since then they might have fixed the dishwasher, or else you quit the job and no longer know or care about the state of the dishwasher.

Answer (score 0):

The past version of “She didn’t tell me that it’s not working” that those teachers would want is “She didn’t tell me that it **wasn’t working**.”

In any event, no such blanket ban on the present tense is reasonable. To illustrate, although there’s nothing wrong with

> She didn’t tell me Paris **was** the capital of France,

it would also be perfectly fine to describe that set of facts by

> She didn’t tell me Paris **is** the capital of France.

Situations where one *could* get in trouble if one were careless about one’s tenses include things like

> She didn’t tell me that Rio de Janeiro was the capital of Brazil.

The risk here arises from the fact that Rio is the *former* capital of Brazil. Today the capital is Brasilia. So which of *was* and *is* might be appropriate (or even correct) depends on context and precisely what one means.